# Xamarin errors Android emulator

Tags: xamarin

Suddenly i start getting following error when i want to run my Xamarin Forms code in Android emulator. I have already set INTERNET in Android Manifest as selected.

{System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure
  at System.Net.WebConnection+d__16.MoveNext () [0x00044] in :0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Net.WebConnection+d__19.MoveNext () [0x000cc] in :0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Net.WebOperation+<Run>d__57.MoveNext () [0x0009a] in <b78695579ed9422b8bc80218eeda782c>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Net.WebCompletionSource`1+d__15[T].MoveNext () [0x00094] in :0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest+d__241`1[T].MoveNext () [0x000ba] in <b78695579ed9422b8bc80218eeda782c>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0001d] in <b78695579ed9422b8bc80218eeda782c>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+d__64.MoveNext () [0x0041d] in :0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+d__64.MoveNext () [0x00478] in :0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>d__49.MoveNext () [0x000ca] in <f26106f7890945d7922088b4caacae4a>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at PetApp.MainPage+d__2.MoveNext () [0x000bc] in C:\Develop\petapp\PetApp\PetApp\MainPage.xaml.cs:38 }

Comment: "NameResolutionFailure" generally means there is a DNS issue

Comment: Like what exact do you mean? It is so annoying, I don't know what to do :(

Comment: the device can't find the address of your server.  This is basic networking troubleshooting.

Comment: But if I do request from e.g. postman to same rest uri it returs expected values. so it works from postman but not from Android emulator

Comment: OK, i got it working by restarting computer :) thx for feedback!